# How to access a HashMap or ArrayList from any part of the application?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, hashmap

Every time I load certain values from database, a HashMap is loaded with certain keys and values from the database, how do I make this HashMap available to all the other classes without having to load the values repeatedly into the HashMap each time it is called:

This is the class which contains method where HashMap is loaded:

```
public class Codes {
    List<CODES> List = null;
         private CodesDAO codesDAO = new CodesDAO(); //DAO Class

    public HashMap <MultiKey,String> fetchCodes(){

        MultiKey multiKey;
        HashMap <MultiKey,String> map = new HashMap<MultiKey,String>();
        List =  codesDAO.fetchGuiCodes();//fetches codes from DB

        for(CODES gui:List){
             multiKey = new MultiKey(gui.getCode(), gui.getKEY());
             map.put(multiKey,gui.getDESC());
        }
        return map;         
    }
}
```

Comment: When is this function called and can you make the calling variable public static?

Comment: The function is called whenever I load certain values from a table and yes calling variable can be public static

Answer (score 2):

You can save your map in a static field, and initialize it in a `static` block. This way it is done only once:

```
public class Codes {
    private static Map<MultiKey, String> codes;
    static {
        CodesDAO codesDAO = new CodesDAO(); // DAO Class
        HashMap<MultiKey, String> map = new HashMap<MultiKey, String>();
        List<CODES> list = codesDAO.fetchGuiCodes();// fetches codes from DB
        for (CODES gui : list) {
            MultiKey multiKey = new MultiKey(gui.getCode(), gui.getKEY());
            map.put(multiKey, gui.getDESC());
        }
        codes = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static Map<MultiKey, String> fetchCodes() {
        return codes;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the codes with:

```
Codes.fetchCodes();
```

Comment: +1 for reminding readers about `Collections.unmodifiableMap`, although of course the OP may not need that. But probably does!

Comment: Calling `Collection#unmodifiableMap()` on every access is unnecessary. Just call it once during map's creation.

Comment: It throws exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Comment: @user2077648: Ah, yes, sorry, my bad. I just thought of the variable definitions as `Map`, since that what they should be. Coding against interfaces is a much better practice than against specific implementations, such as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

If static fields are not an option, you could lazily initialise as follows:

```
private HashMap<MultiKey, String> map = null;

public HashMap<MultiKey, String> fetchCodes() {

  if (map == null) {
    map = new HashMap<MultiKey, String>();
    list = codesDAO.fetchGuiCodes();// fetches codes from DB

    for (CODES gui : list) {
      MultiKey multiKey = new MultiKey(gui.getCode(), gui.getKEY());
      map.put(multiKey, gui.getDESC());
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

Note: this is not thread-safe, but could be with some additional synchronization.

Comment: It is giving me NullPointer Excection for  map.put(multiKey, gui.getDESC());

Comment: I'm guessing you're either using multiple threads or you've made a mistake in copying my code.

Answer (score 0):

May be load the data only once? Use memoization(I would) from guava:

```
  Suppliers.memoize(//Implementation of Supplier<T>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring, you could simply declare a bean (singleton) and implement the InitializingBean interface.

You would be forced to implement a method called afterPropertiesSet() and load your Map there.

If you don't use Spring, you could initialize your map at the start like you did and put it in
the servletConext.  this scope is availbale from all session.

This is all good for read-only data.  if you need to update it, be carefull because this will not be thread-safe.  you will have to make it thread-safe.

hope it help

regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the OP designed his Java EE application and if any 3rd party frameworks are been used, but in a properly designed standard Java EE application using EJB, CDI, JPA, transactions and all on em, the DB is normally not available in static context. The answers which suggest to initialize it statically are in such case severely misleading and broken.

The canonical approach is to [just create one](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne) instance holding the preinitialized data and reuse it throughout application's lifetime. With the current Java EE standards, this can be achieved by creating and initializing the bean once during application's startup and storing it in the application scope. For example, an application scoped CDI bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    private List<Code> codes;

    @EJB
    private DataService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        codes = Collections.unmodifiableList(service.getAllCodes());
    }

    public List<Code> getCodes() {
        return codes;
    }

}
```

This is then available by `#{data.codes}` anywhere else in the application.